# Google App Script pageToken to save attachments to Google Drive

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-apps-script-api

basically what I'm trying to do is to get all the attachments within the received emails to a folder in google Drive (there are many, mostly .PDF). But it says I can't go beyond 500 attached files with search function and that I have to use something called pageToken which I have no idea how to apply to my code. So I need some advice or guide or maybe some examples to do this.

```js
function saveGmailtoGoogleDrive() {

  const folderId = '1apaQJjDSK-bNfd3ZgiFqK23cE7SCPqoB'; //Google Drive Folder

  const searchQuery = 'label:unread has:attachment'; //Filter

  const threads = GmailApp.search(searchQuery, 0, 500);

  

  threads.forEach(thread => {
    const messages = thread.getMessages();
    messages.forEach(message => {

      const attachments = message.getAttachments({
          includeInlineImages: false,
          includeAttachments: true
          
      });

      attachments.forEach(attachment => {

        // Insert the attachment to google drive folder

        Drive.Files.insert(
          {
            title: attachment.getName(),
            mimeType: attachment.getContentType(),
            parents: [{ id: folderId }]
          },
          attachment.copyBlob()
        );
      });
    });
  });
};
```

```js
function saveGmailtoGoogleDrive() {

  const folderId = '1apaQJjDSK-bNfd3ZgiFqK23cE7SCPqoB'; //Google Drive Folder

  const searchQuery = 'label:unread has:attachment'; //Filter

  const threads = GmailApp.search(searchQuery, 0, 500);

  

  threads.forEach(thread => {
    const messages = thread.getMessages();
    messages.forEach(message => {

      const attachments = message.getAttachments({
          includeInlineImages: false,
          includeAttachments: true
          
      });

      attachments.forEach(attachment => {

        // Insert the attachment to google drive folder

        Drive.Files.insert(
          {
            title: attachment.getName(),
            mimeType: attachment.getContentType(),
            parents: [{ id: folderId }]
          },
          attachment.copyBlob()
        );
      });
    });
  });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

The arguments of the method of `search(query, start, max)` are `query, start, max`. The current maximum value of `max` is `500`. When this value is over, an error like `Argument max cannot exceed 500.` occurs. And, `start` is the start position of the search. So I thought that this can be used for achieving your goal. When this is reflected in your script, it becomes as follows.

#### Modified script:

##### From:

```js
const threads = GmailApp.search(searchQuery, 0, 500);
```

##### To:

```js
let [start, end] = [0, 500];
let threads = [];
do {
  const t = GmailApp.search(searchQuery, start, end);
  start += end;
  threads = [...threads, ...t];
} while (threads.length == start);
```

- By this modification, you can retrieve the emails in `threads` more than 500.

#### Reference:

- [search(query, start, max)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-app#searchquery,-start,-max)

Comment: Hey, thanks for taking your time to reply to my question. I tried the way you showed me but I can't still make it work, it keeps saying this: "Error Exception: Argument max cannot exceed 500." I replaced  const threads = GmailApp.search(searchQuery, 0, 500); to the modification you suggested but I keep getting the same error. Do you know by chance how could I apply the pageToken to my code? or how could I make it work I'd really appreciate your help please

Comment: @Gabriel Belt Thank you for replying. I apologize for the inconvenience. Unfortunately, I cannot replicate your situation of `Error Exception: Argument max cannot exceed 500.`. When I tested my proposed script, no error occurs. So can you provide your current script for replicating your issue? By this, I would like to confirm your current issue. About `how could I apply the pageToken to my code?`, `GmailApp.search` doesn't use the pageToken. I apologize for this. Can you provide the official document of the pageToken you expect?